# "Method range of global object" error

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the format of the program I am trying to run.  The idea is that a user enters values into columns E through L in Excel and this program uses those values to auto-calculate a sum, which it puts into column M.

```
Sub Button12_Click()

Dim JobTwoDescription() As String
Dim JobOneJobTwoDescription() As String
Dim Length() As Range
Dim Width() As Range
Dim Quantity() As Range
Dim JobTwoTime() As Range
Dim JobOneTime As Range
Dim TotalTime As Range
Dim i As Integer

ReDim JobTwoDescription(i), JobOneJobTwoDescription(i), Length(i), Width(i), Quantity(i), JobTwoTime(i), Staples(i), Grid(i)

For i = 1 to 10

    JobTwoTime(i) = Range("Mi")
    JobTwoDescription(i) = Range("Ei")
    JobOneJobTwoDescription(i) = Range("Fi")
    Length(i) = Range("Ji")
    Width(i) = Range("Ki")
    Quantity(i) = Range("Li")
    JobOneTime = 0 'Initialize to zero
    TotalTime = 0 'Initialize to zero

    If LCase(JobOneDescription(i)) = "Option 1" Then JobOneTime(i) = A

    If LCase(JobOneDescription(i)) = "Option 2" Then JobOneTime(i) = B

    If LCase(JobOneDescription(i)) = "Option 3" Then JobOneTime(i) = C


    If LCase(JobTwoDescription(i)) = "Option4" Then

    If Length(i) + Width(i) <= X Then JobTwoTime(i) = + D* Quantity(i)

    ElseIf Length(i) + Width(i) > X & Length(i) + Width(i) <= Y Then JobTwoTime(i) = E* Quantity(i)

    ElseIf Length(i) + Width(i) > Y & Length(i) + Width(i) <= Z Then JobTwoTime(i) = F * Quantity(i)

    End If

    TotalTime(i) = JobTwoTime(i) + JobOneTime(i)

    ws.Range("Mi") = TotalTime(i)

Next i
End Sub
```

The error is coming up at "JobTwoTime(i) = Range("Mi")".  I know it's an issue with `i`, though I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Change the declarations of your variables.  You don't need arrays of Range objects.

Change

```
Dim JobTwoTime() As Range
```

To

```
Dim JobTwoTime As Double
```

And change

```
JobTwoTime(i) = Range("Mi")
```

to

```
JobTwoTime = Range("M" & i).Value
```

The .Value is not required as it is the default property of the Range object, but I use it.

Comment: to be more clear all references with `Range("*n*i)` need to be changed the way that MatthewD suggests to `Range("*n*" & i)`, where *n* is the column reference.

Comment: Thanks!  Although now I'm getting a "subscript out of range" error in the same location.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would use a range array.  Unless you really need range objects i would define them as strings or integer, long, or doubles depending on the values you are loading into them.  So change Dim JobTwoTime() As Range to Dim JobTwoTime(10) As Integer and size the array by putting a 10 demension.

Comment: I realize now I made a mistake in the initial steps...JobOneTime, JobTwoTime, and TotalTime are all calculations that take place in the program...there is no initial value.  They can take on any value above 0 and are not integers, aka can be decimals.  What would be the best Dim...as XXXX?

Comment: Dim JobOneTime As Double will be best for you.  There is a single datatype for small decimals.  And it looks like you only use the current values so I don't think you need arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks that seems to work, although now I'm getting an "expected array" error where I initialized to zero, the code has slightly changed from the original to "JobOneTime = 0, JobTwoTime=0, TotalTime=0"

Comment: Did you take the () off of you variable where you use it.  JobTwoTime = Range("M" & i).Value

Comment: Sorry no I did not.  It looks like: TotalTime(i) = 0 etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  This is very, very close to working.  The final issue is the last line of code "ws.Range("M" & i) = TotalTime" which returns "Object required".  I tried putting "set" in front of the code but that returned the same error.